# Настройка библиотеки kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Научился в Python с помощью **Kivy** создавать виджет кнопки, который можно перетаскивать по экрану, менять размер и тд. Но при передвижении, изменении размера остаётся след на экране.

Также, создал переменную `label = Label()` и отобразил на экран. При изменении `label.text` предыдущий текст, также, остаётся на экране, а новый накладывается поверх него. Как изменить такое поведение, чтобы не оставалось следов?

Comment: Код дайте. Он у вас не верный.

Comment: Проблему уже решил. Изменил цвет текста у виджета Label, потом убрал из кода это изменение. Волшебным образом проблема исчезла.